# Repair garage floor fiber board

Tags: garage

The very end of the fiber board strip, which you can't see behind the trim, has worn down--there's a hole in it--and water from rain gets into the garage there.

Everywhere else, the strip is fine so what can I do to properly fill in the hole in the strip?

[image]

Comment: The photo is not showing us the problem. A closer look may help. Is the felt strip a filler in the expansion gap of the concrete slab ?? Or a gasket attached to the door or slab. ??

Comment: @AlaskaMan The problem is that there is a hole dug into the felt letting water in.

Comment: Rob,  i understand that. I was saying that the photo does not show us the hole. More info on the strip and how it attached  would be helpful.

Comment: Is that a threshold? That is falling apart , kind of hard to see. Is that a “man door” or a large roll up, swing up door?